# How do I compose a type that "NOT"s a different type?

Tags: typescript

Sorry if none of this makes sense, but I'm super confused at how to do the typings here.

I have some interfaces like so:

```
interface AAA { a: string; }
interface BBB { b: string; }
interface CCC { c: string; }
interface DDD { d: string; }
```

This is my use-case for a "NOT" type:

```
// I'm not even sure if this is a correct or useful type...
type SomeType<T> = T extends { a: string } ? AAA 
                   : T extends { b: string } ? BBB
                   : T extends { c: string } ? CCC
                   : DDD;

class AlphabetNode<T> {
  // How do I specify "NOT<T>" in typescript? I tried using "Exclude<any, T>" but it
  // doesn't prevent "T" objects from being pushed into the array.
  public children: SomeType<NOT<T>>[] = [];

  constructor(public data: SomeType<T>) {}
}

// I would prefer to not have to specify the type "AAA" if there exists a solution.
const x: AlphabetNode<AAA> = new AlphabetNode({ a: 'I like the letter A' });

// Valid
x.children.push({ b: 'This should be valid' });
x.children.push({ c: 'This should also be valid' });

// Both of these statements should be invalid, but as my types are currently set up, 
// typescript is fine with both.
x.children.push({ b: 'Uh', c: 'Oh' });
x.children.push({ a: 'Why is this valid?' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've been playing around with this and I found a partial solution that I'll have to go with for now...

```
interface AAA { a: string }
interface BBB { b: string }
interface CCC { c: string }
interface DDD { d: string }

type WhichAlphabet<T> = T extends AAA ? AAA 
                      : T extends BBB ? BBB 
                      : T extends CCC ? CCC 
                      : T extends DDD ? DDD : never;

class AlphabetNode<T> {
  public children: Exclude<WhichAlphabet<any>, T>[] = [];

  constructor(public data: WhichAlphabet<T>) {}
}

const a = new AlphabetNode<AAA>({ a: 'Letter a' });
a.children.push({ b: 'Letter b' }); // Ok
a.children.push({ c: 'Letter c' }); // Ok
a.children.push({ d: 'Letter d' }); // Ok
a.children.push({ x: 'Letter x' }); // invalid
a.children.push({ a: 'Another letter a' }); // invalid
```

So that's all fine and dandy, but the only issue becomes...

```
a.children.push({ b: 'Another letter b', c: 'Another letter c' }); // Ok
```

At this point I'll just have to roll with it because I've wasted too much time already. Maybe this will help someone come up with the "real" answer.